# URL be able to not type .php in url and direct to php file

Tags: url

i want to make this page http://www.jambagames.com/index.php to not show the ".php" at the end.  Is it also possible to make php files my default on my godaddy server?  Such as typing in http://www.jambagames.com/index and it'll go to that index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

The process that you are asking here is to rewrite the URL's

To rewrite http://www.jambagames.com/index.php into http://www.jambagames.com/index you need to use these directives in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @MyVan copy paste the contents of your .htaccess file on server to pastebin & setexpiry to 1 week.